# SessionFactory creation Exception Thrown When Running on localhost

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I have a simple maven project setup with a java class that creates a `SessionFactory` from a hibernate.cfg.xml - when I run this application from a main method it executes fine:

Test.java

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Starting App");
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    //do some stuff
    //success
}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            System.out.println("Opening Session Factory...");
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());         
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

However, when I run this same app on my Tomcat Application Server it calls my RestController class which creates the SessionFactory the same way:

Controller.java

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    MyClass class = null;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{searchQuery}", produces = "application/json")
    public String search(@PathVariable String searchQuery) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Starting Session...");
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        //do some stuff
}
```

And the following exception is returned:

```
Starting Session...
Opening Session Factory... //Inside HibernateUtil.java
Mar 09, 2015 11:54:47 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2.1
Mar 09, 2015 11:54:47 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 09, 2015 11:54:47 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
Mar 09, 2015 11:54:47 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Mar 09, 2015 11:54:48 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 09, 2015 11:54:48 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.test.dto.MyClassDTO"/>
Mar 09, 2015 11:54:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [MyClass] in context with path [/test] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.test.dto.MyClassDTO"/>
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1597)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1552)
```

I believe this exception is misleading, as I have no need to instantiate an `AnnotationConfiguration`; `Configuration` works just fine. What could be the reason this exception is thrown while run on my Application Container?

EDIT: hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <!--  Database Connection String -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:55555/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>

        <!--  C3p0 Settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>

       <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="com.test.dto.MyClassDTO"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your Hibernate.cfg.xml. On a side note, I would not recommend putting your transactional context within your Controller.

Comment: Added hibernate.cfg.xml - and thanks for the tip; transactional context is currently only there for connection testing purposes